# Whether session cookie expires at midnight?

Tags: web, google-analytics, browser, session-cookies, web-analytics

I am working in Web anlaytics, I am using cookies for tracking visits, pageviews as same as  [google analytics](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2731565?hl=en). Whether `session cookie` expires at midnight or we have to enforce the expiration.

I am having two question

1.Whether session cookie expires at [midnight(11:59:59pm)](http://lordwhitney.co.uk/privacy-and-cookies)?

2.If its expires why?

Any idea will be greatful.

Comment: A cookie expires at the time set in the cookie when you send it. Making a session expire at midnight sounds like a horrible idea; Why should your site work differently for someone visiting for 10 minutes at 11:55 at night than it is for someone visiting at 11:55 in the morning?

Comment: @wooble Actually i want to calculate the visits per day basis. eg: the visits after 11:59:59pm is taken as next day visit.

Answer (score 0):

With the last round of changes to the definition of a visit/session in GA, I recall a new session would be generated if a user continues an existing one past midnight.

Edit: Here is the definition https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2731565?hl=en